# Etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; cannot validate certificate; because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, kubernetes

So I'm trying to create a pod on a Kubernetes cluster. Here is the yml file from which I am creating the pod.

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod2
spec:
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container2
      image: <<image_name>>
```

The pod hangs at container creating. Here is the output of kubectl describe pod.

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                    SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                    -------------   --------    ------      -------
  10s       10s     1   default-scheduler                   Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned task-pv-pod2 to ip-10-205-234-170.ec2.internal
  8s        8s      1   kubelet, ip-10-205-234-170.ec2.internal         Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "SetupNetwork" for "task-pv-pod2_default" with SetupNetworkError: "NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"task-pv-pod2_default\" network: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.234.170 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n; error #1: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.235.160 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n; error #2: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.234.162 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n"

  7s    6s  2   kubelet, ip-10-205-234-170.ec2.internal     Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "TeardownNetwork" for "task-pv-pod2_default" with TeardownNetworkError: "NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod \"task-pv-pod2_default\" network: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.234.170 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n; error #1: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.235.160 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n; error #2: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.205.234.162 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n"
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this. In order to Kubernetes to work with aws as a cloud provider I had to set a proxy variable in the hyperkube container. Co

Answer (score 0):

It seem your ETCD's certs as not trusted for the name (or IP) you access on. I suggest to you to check your cluster health with `kubectl get cs` and modify k8s way to talk to ETCD if needed.